# Dapper parameter expansion and FROM clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

It seems to me that the parameter expansion in FROM clauses only works for certain parameter types; running the below snippet throws the following exception `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'` when attempting to run a query with a string array parameter.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    var sql = "SELECT ids.id FROM @ids ids (id)";
    conn.Query(sql, new { ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }); // This works perfectly
    conn.Query(sql, new { ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" } // This query throws an exception
}
```

I've struggled to find any documentation regarding this kind of parameter expansion, so my question is whether I've bumped into an undocumented an partially supported feature (perhaps by misusing the parameter expansion), or is this a bug?

Comment: You get `SqlException` so you have bad syntax in your sql query. IMHO you try to search integer column with char values. It obviously will not work.

Comment: @MaciejS.Yes indeed, the expanded query is of incorrect syntax (as the exception clearly implies). Are you saying that dapper list parameter expansion implicitly assumes the data type to be that of integers?

Comment: Try to run the queries when [Sql Server profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) is running, so that you can see exactly what the sql created by dapper looks like.

Comment: Leave aside dapper for a second... can you clarify what syntax you're trying to emulate? This doesn't look like a regular `in` query, which is what dapper's expansion aims for. Happy to help (primary Dapper maintainer), but... very unclear!

Comment: From what I can see, your "This works perfectly" scenario is working as a complete accident; that was never the intended/supported use of that feature

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes I arrived to the same conclusion in my answer from analysing captured events. What I was trying to achieve was a query of the form SELECT ids.id  FROM (VALUES ("1"), ("2"), ("3")) ids (Id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the hint from Zohar I created an xe-session to capture the statements run by dapper. The parameter expansion is indeed handled very differently for string list parameters

```
-- first query
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ids.id FROM (select cast([value] as int) from string_split(@ids,'','')) ids (id)',N'@ids varchar(max) ',@ids='1,2,3,4,5'

-- second query
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ids.id FROM (@ids1,@ids2,@ids3,@ids4,@ids5) ids (id)',N'@ids1 nvarchar(4000),@ids2 nvarchar(4000),@ids3 nvarchar(4000),@ids4 nvarchar(4000),@ids5 nvarchar(4000)',@ids1=N'1',@ids2=N'2',@ids3=N'3',@ids4=N'4',@ids5=N'5'
```

Both expansion patterns produce valid syntax for `WHERE IN` clauses, but not for `FROM` clauses. So, in the end, partial support for parameter expansion in `FROM` clauses seems to be something resulting from a misuse of the framework.

Comment: indeed, the expansion syntax in Dapper is only intended for use with `in` queries, and is only tested for that usage; if you think this is a useful scenario to support more generally, then maybe propose it on github - ideally with examples of when this would be useful